# Autogenerate UUID or timeuuid in spring-data Cassandra?

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data, uuid, spring-data-cassandra

I am using spring-data-cassandra. Is there a way or an annotation, which can be used in my entity java POJO for the primary key of type uuid or timeuuid,to auto-generate the value of the primary key(id)?

I know that I can use `id = UUIDs.timeBased();`, but I want to automate it.

Answer (score 8):

You could always implement the default constructor:

```
MyEntity() {
    id = UUIDs.timeBased();
}
```

Would that be enough? This would obviously require an unnecessary generation on instantiation which would consume some random entropy on your system. However, if your system is not running with too much high pressure you should be safe.

Comment: Good call.  I was also wondering why he didn't just do that, too.

Answer (score 3):

Although, `id` can be initialized in default constructor. However, it will result in unnecessary generation of `UUIDs`.

One better approach is to exploit multiple constructor of the POJO class -

**Default constructor** -

```
public MyEntity() {

}
```

**Parametrized constructor -** Pass all the fields except `id` field in constructor. This constructor should be called in application code. Type and no. of fields can vary -

```
public MyEntity(String field1) {
     this.field1 = field1;
     this.id = UUIDs.timeBased();
}
```

One major benefit of using this approach is - default constructor is used by `Spring` for mapping `CQL` with POJO class, for example in `SELECT` query response.

So, by this way, unnecessary generation of `UUID` can be avoided by `Spring framework` and some optimization can be done.